# Cannot find module '@amcharts/amcharts5' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, amcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og43S.jpg)Getting for all the references of am charts like XYChart, XYCursor, Legend, etc.,. Tried with am charts versions 5.1.12, 5.1.13, and the latest one.

Tried to use xy charts from AM charts, which was working fine like 10 days before, but when i tried to use now, getting this error.

**Tried with previous versions like 5.1.12, 13.
**Tried installing the package with -dev
**Deleted node modules and did npm i

None of the above worked